# Youtube iFrame Javascript API not always loading website video

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I have a Django website homepage which displays a looping, YouTube video on startup via the iFrame Youtube API. However, to prevent the Youtube loading animation or to avoid a blank area on incompatable devices, I have a picture initially appear in position and then have it fade into the Youtube video using a timer delay. However, the Youtube API is not consistent, and at times the Youtube video does not appear (stays stuck on image).

I have attached the JS and CSS which runs these elements. I am unsure if this inconsistency is a result of the code itself, or whether it is because of slow internet speeds/excessive loading. I have seen some comments of ensuring the API function is global, but I believe this script already is.

**Javascript: iFrame Youtube API**

```
<script async src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<script async src="video.js"></script>
<script>
    window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
        var player;
        player = new YT.Player('YouTubeBackgroundVideoPlayer', {
            videoId: 'LKXNZT1z9cs', // YouTube Video ID
            width: 1280,               // Player width (in px)
            height: 720,              // Player height (in px)
            playerVars: {
                playlist: 'LKXNZT1z9cs',
                autoplay: 1,        // Auto-play the video on load
                autohide: 1,
                disablekb: 1,
                controls: 0,        // Hide pause/play buttons in player
                showinfo: 0,        // Hide the video title
                modestbranding: 0,  // Hide the Youtube Logo
                loop: 1,            // Run the video in a loop
                fs: 0,              // Hide the full screen button
                autohide: 0,         // Hide video controls when playing
                rel: 0,
                enablejsapi: 1
            },
            events: {
                onReady: function onPlayerReady(event) {
                    goToStart(event);
                },
                onStateChange: function (e) {
                    if (e && e.data === 1) {
                        var videoHolder = document.getElementById('home-banner-box');
                        if (videoHolder && videoHolder.id) {
                            videoHolder.classList.remove('loading');
                        }
                    } else if (e && e.data === 0) {
                        e.target.playVideo()
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

---

**CSS**

```
.home-banner .slide .video-slide {
  background-color: #000; }

.home-banner.loading .video-background {
  opacity: 0; }

.video-background {
  position: relative;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-0%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-0%);
  transform: translateY(-0%);
  -webkit-transition: 2s opacity ease;
  transition: 2s opacity ease;
  transition-delay: 2.8s;
  opacity: 1; }

.video-foreground,
.video-background iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none; }
```

Comment: does defining `window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` before loading the other script fix it? I could see how the YouTube code would try to fire that "event" before it's defined, and never try again after that.

Comment: It seems to still be having the same trouble even after placing the top two scripts on the bottom. Interestingly, it seems to be having more trouble in Chrome than Firefox.

Comment: Is your html element with the id YouTubeBackgroundVideoPlayer before or after the iframe scripts? It should be before.